# MySQL AND/OR SELECT Statement multiple values in field

Tags: mysql

I have a simple enough query that works well:

```
SELECT 
     Name, JobStatus 
FROM 
     ScheduleRequest
WHERE
     ScheduleDate >= '2018-07-11' 
AND 
     JobStatus <> 6
```

I need to check for different values in the same field 'JobStatus'.  When I try to alter the query like this, I'm finding only the last value of 95 is showing?

```
SELECT 
     Name, JobStatus
FROM 
    ScheduleRequest
WHERE
    ScheduleDate >= '2018-07-11' 
    AND (JobStatus <> 6 
        OR JobStatus <> 0 
        OR JobStatus <> 1
        OR JobStatus <> 4
        OR JobStatus <> 95
    )
```

Comment: Notice how everything will match as no record can have all of the values assigned to a single filed. What you wanted probably is to either use `AND` instead of `OR` or just use the proposed answer with `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` expression

```
SELECT 
     Name, JobStatus
FROM 
    ScheduleRequest
WHERE
     ScheduleDate >= '2018-07-11' 

    AND JobStatus NOT IN (6, 0, 1, 4, 95)
```